# Error extracting an archive using `tarfile`

Tags: python, python-3.x, archive, tarfile, gunzip

I am getting an error while trying to extract a `.tar.gz` archive using [the `tarfile` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html).

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```py
# `gzip_archive_bytes_content` is the content of the gzip archive, in "bytes" format
repo_sources_file_object = io.BytesIO(gzip_archive_bytes_content)
repo_sources_tar_object = tarfile.TarFile(fileobj=repo_sources_file_object)
repo_sources_tar_object.extractall(path="/tmp/")
```

This the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/tarfile.py", line 186, in nti
    s = nts(s, "ascii", "strict")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/tarfile.py", line 170, in nts
    return s.decode(encoding, errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/tarfile.py", line 2289, in next
    tarinfo = self.tarinfo.fromtarfile(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/tarfile.py", line 1095, in fromtarfile
    obj = cls.frombuf(buf, tarfile.encoding, tarfile.errors)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/tarfile.py", line 1037, in frombuf
    chksum = nti(buf[148:156])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/tarfile.py", line 189, in nti
    raise InvalidHeaderError("invalid header")
tarfile.InvalidHeaderError: invalid header

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/my-package/__main__.py", line 87, in <module>
    function(**function_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/my-package/chart.py", line 107, in reinstall
    install()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/my-package/chart.py", line 89, in install
    repo_sources_tar_object = tarfile.TarFile(fileobj=repo_sources_file_object)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/tarfile.py", line 1484, in __init__
    self.firstmember = self.next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/tarfile.py", line 2301, in next
    raise ReadError(str(e))
tarfile.ReadError: invalid header
```

Python version: 3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched from instanciating directly a [`tarfile.TarFile` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile-objects) to using [the `tarfile.open()` constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.open), and it fixed it:

```py
repo_sources_tar_object = tarfile.open(fileobj=repo_sources_file_object)
```

There is actually a warning on this in the documentation, [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile):

> Do not use this class directly: use tarfile.open() instead.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to use a context manager in order to automatically close the file when the job is done.

One could write:

```py
import contextlib
import io
import tarfile

gzip_archive_bytes_content = b"..."
repo_sources_file_object = io.BytesIO(gzip_archive_bytes_content)

with contextlib.closing(tarfile.open(fileobj=repo_sources_file_object)) as arch:
    arch.extractall(path="/tmp/")
```

This is available with `tarfile.TarFile`, but not with `tarfile.open()`.
So you could write:

```py
with tarfile.TarFile(...) as arch:
    ...
```